# Getting an updated e1000e module for 20.04 LTS fips - (17) I219-LM

Tags: 20.04

Is the only means to get modern e1000e hardware support in a fips kernel to rebuild the kernel with self-signed certs?

The e1000e module supplied with 20.04 LTS Desktop works out of the box. The module supplied with 20.04 LTS Server does not but is resolved by installing the HWE kernel. Enabling fips breaks both Desktop and Server. The fips environment requires signed modules so manual build and replace doesn't seem to be the path. Is it likely Ubuntu would be responsive to making module versions consistent across their releases? Intel's release that added support for the I219-LM coming with commodity Dell hardware is from 2020.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question: 2020 hardware is too new for the 2019-2020 kernel in non-HWE 20.04 Ubuntu Server. But not too new for the 2022-era kernel in the HWE 20.04 Ubuntu Desktop. Ubuntu DID make versions consistent across releases for over a decade. Folks complained that the kernels were too old, hence HWE.

Comment: No, as noted HWE is not required for desktop. Server and fips variants of either edition are behind the curve. My concern is with how to get fips up to snuff. The only apparent path is to rebuild the kernel. My question is whether that is "correct" or if alternatives are available.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494358/edit) to cite the exact kernel package name versions that you are having trouble with. This will prevent a lot of "it was included with" confusion. Use apt to determine the package name and version (not uname).